# Get all value after ":" in a file in JS

Tags: javascript

I've got a file .config:

```
login: toto
password: tata
```

I want to display only the value after : and stock it into a variable like:

```
console.log(firstVariable); //toto 
console.log(secondVariable); //tata
```

What I'm doing :

```
var text = fs.readFileSync(".config", "utf-8").trim();
var arr = text.split("\n")
console.log(arr); [ 'login: toto','password: tata' ]

let tab = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  var splitResult = arr[i].split(":");
  var expectedValue = splitResult[1].replace(/["']/g, "").slice(0,-1);
  tab.push(expectedValue);
}

var firstVariable = tab[0]
var secondVariable = tab[1]

console.log(firstVariable);
console.log(secondVariable);
```

Actual result:

- (one space)tot
- (one space)tat

Expected result:

- toto
- tata

Comment: split by colon+space `arr[i].split(": ")`

Comment: `slice(0,-1)` means you truncate your string at 1 character from the end. The space is expected, since you split on ':' and there's a space after in your config. You may use `trim` to remove extra spaces, and update your slice

Comment: please check the answer did my answer help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a space after colon string ": "  (previously ":")

and remove the `.slice()` or use `.trim()`

```js
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  var splitResult = arr[i].split(": "); // Add a space after colon
  var expectedValue = splitResult[1].replace(/["']/g, ""); //remove the slice
  tab.push(expectedValue);
}
```

For using `trim()`:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  var splitResult = arr[i].split(":");
  var expectedValue = splitResult[1].replace(/["']/g, "").trim(); //replace the slice with trim
  tab.push(expectedValue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `trim()` to remove the space

```js
var arr = [ 'login: toto','password: tata' ]

let tab = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  var splitResult = arr[i].split(":");
  var expectedValue = splitResult[1].replace(/["']/g, "").trim();
  tab.push(expectedValue);
}

var firstVariable = tab[0]
var secondVariable = tab[1]

console.log(firstVariable);
console.log(secondVariable);
```